# SQLite: grouping results by date and average

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following columns:

```
startTime (int), elapsedTime (int), name (string)
```

the startTime column is a unix epoch timestamp  and the elapsedTime column is in seconds.

I was looking for a query that could

1) group the startTime column into groups of 24 hours (3600 secs). That column is already represented as seconds
2) for each of the 24 hour groups, group the steps by name 
3) for each of the name groups, calculate the average elapsedTime of each name in that group

Example result:

```
startTime, name, avgElapsedTime<br>
102324433, program1, 2994.4<br>
102324433, program2, 232.3<br>
102324433, program3, 234.1<br>
146325433, program1, 499.1<br>
146325433, program2, 5599.1<br>
146325433, program6, 155.1<br>
```

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Note that there are actually 86,400 seconds in 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this might give you the results you are after:

```
SELECT
  CAST(startTime % 86400 / 3600 AS INTEGER) AS hour,
  name,
  AVG(elapsedTime) AS avgElapsedTime
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  CAST(startTime % 86400 / 3600 AS INTEGER),
  name
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date(startTime, 'unixepoch'), avg(elapsedTime), name FROM tableName Group by 1, 3